# The derivatives of the integrals with Leibniz Rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Can we obtain the following result for  ...  $f(x)={x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$ ...  ? 
 It is very simple but important question. Here ${\lfloor x \rfloor}$  is floor function  and  $a \in \mathbb{R}$ . Thank you for your kind comment.

$$
\frac{{\frac {d} {du}}\left[\int_1^u f(x) \cdot x^{-a-1} dx\right]}
     {{\frac {d} {du}}\left[\int_1^u f(x) \cdot x^{a-2}dx\right]}
=u^{1-2a}
$$

Comment: Why is this important? And what were your attempts solving this problem?

Comment: We are discussing about it very seriously with some mathematicians .

Comment: Can I get a more solid answer  ?  I mean we can obtain or not ?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. For any (constant) $a \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\frac{d}{dz} \int_a^z f(u)du = f(z).
$$
That should simplify your problem greatly.

**UPDATE**

In your case $f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, so it has a countable number of discontinuities, which does not prevent the Riemann integral from existing. You have to define, for example,
$$
\int_1^x g(f(u)) du 
  := \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x g(f(u))du
   + \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \int_1^k g(f(u)) du.
$$
This way, all the integrals on the RHS are well-defined and the LHS can be defined in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Testform why not? discontinuities in $f$ are discrete, it is still integrable.

Comment: I have thought exactly like you. Even, I have tested  it only with  f(x)  on Wolfram/Alpha. And I got the result exactly what you said.  But  I can not verify it     for  $f(x)={x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$  ,  the program gives nothing.

Comment: @Testform see update

Comment: thus,  it means  can we obtain the result in my question?

Comment: Thank you my freind. But someone say that you can not obtain it for $f(x)={x-\lfloor x \rfloor}$ . He say : Because, the floor function is not differentiable

Comment: what can you  say now ?  Can we obtain the result in my question  or  not ? According to my idea, yes we can.

Comment: @Testform see the update, even if $f$ is not differentiable, but integrable, the integral of $f$ is differentiable...